# One click Google Sign In for Pre-Launch report

Tags: java, android, google-signin

To use [Pre-Launch report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270) on Google Play as per [guideline](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270), it's needed to build a custom alpha apk which would let a "robot" pass via the Sign-in button to the main app screen:

> If your app opens directly to a sign-in screen with required credentials (app-specific, social media), you may get limited results since test devices can't skip these screens during testing.
>
> To run more complete tests of your app, you can publish an alpha or beta APK with a sign-in button that allows a test device to continue testing your app with a single click.
>
> For example, you could publish an alpha APK with a "Sign in using test account" button that loads your app with preloaded account information.

**Question**: is it possible to set up such a "fake google sign-in button" so that it has imbedded account name/password of a real testing account?

Answer (score 0):

Google now gives you the option of providing sign in credentials for a test account to "allow the crawler to explore your app beyond its login screen". Currently you just need to scroll to the bottom of the Pre-Launch report page and there's a little box titled "Sign-in credentials".